# difference in initialization constructor

Tags: c++

I have a simple class with two objects in main(). Are there any differences in the initialization of the constructor ?

```
//#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Simple
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        Simple(int b) : a(b) { }
        void show() { std::cout << a; }
};


int main()
{
    Simple firstObj = Simple(5);
    firstObj.show();

    Simple secondObj(5);
    secondObj.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Pre-C++17,

  first one uses also copy(Pre-c++11)/move constructor (which might be elided) whereas second uses only `Simple(int)`.
- Since C++17,

  both are equivalent.

Comment: Your Pre-C++17 description is a Pre-C++11 description. [C++11, C++17) description is same except move constructor would be used.

Answer (score 1):

`Simple firstObj = Simple(5);` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), `Simple secondObj(5);` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), since C++17 they have the exact same effect: the object is initialized by the constructor `Simple::Simple(int)` directly.